# Search for asked questions in app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Please add a search field where one could search for a question that had been asked before, without having to use a search engine in browser.
Please if there exist such a feature, you can make it easily accessible by users.

Comment: Ran into that use case just this morning ... and many times in the past. Especially if you know there is a duplicate, it's annoying to have to spend time outside of the app, and copy/pasting. In the browser you at least get a set of suggestions... it would be helpful if you could search on "possible duplicate answers that I wrote" with a simple check box, too.

Comment: Uh...when you select a site in the app, there's a search box at the top of the screen. What "search" are you missing?